# Ubuntu, Apache2.4 ban bad agents globally

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I want to ban bad agents. I have tried many way [including this one!](https://gist.github.com/iAugur/35345f738baa7f8699b7)

But it doesn't work. If I create a perl file: [check this!](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/the-rise-of-bots-spammers-crack-attacks-and-libwww-perl.html)

I think this is because of `Order deny,allow` syntax as it is for apache2.2!
I want to create a file `badagents.conf` where I will put all the bad agents (like done in link 1) and then create a common `banbadagents.conf` that I just include in my vhost because I have like 9 vhosts. And changing something in all of them is really problematic.

How to globally ban the agents listed in `badagents.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

If you think this

> I think this is because of Order deny,allow syntax as it is for apache2.2!

then the obvious thing to try is [converting it to the relevant 2.4 access control syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

Comment: That was the first obvious thing I already tried but I can not find a coversion for `deny from env=BadAgent`!

Comment: You need to tell us what you've done so we don't waste our time then.

Comment: Sorry for that. I tried to do so by providing the link. I have done exactly as mentioned in the link and it did not worked!